# Add a Unity/Vuforia Scene Into a React Native App [Android]

Tags: android, react-native, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I would like to know if it is possible to correctly add a Unity/Vuforia Scene into a React Native app for Android devices and, consequently, being able to share data between React Native and Unity/Vuforia, and vice-versa (some kind of "bridge"). For example, by clicking on a React Native button being able to launch a Unity/Vuforia Scene and by clicking on a button in the Unity/Vuforia Scene being able to update some data in a variable in React Native.

On the other hand, if it is really possible, how can I do this? I would like a few tutorials or samples to be able to implement this in my React Native mobile app.

Thank you!